# Android Dynamically populate a custom listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a problem populating a custom layout listview on click. I have no experience in java and ArrayLists. My code is mainly built using tutorials on the web. I learn a lot faster by example.
So, I have a class for the custom item and an Adapter for it. They go like this:

```
public class Prodf {
        public int icon;
        public String id;
        public String nume;
        public String um;
        public String pu;
        public String cant;
        public Prodf(){
            super();
        }

        public Prodf(int icon, String id, String nume, String um, String pu, String cant) {
            super();
            this.icon = icon;
            this.id = id;
            this.nume = nume;
            this.um = um;
            this.pu = pu;
            this.cant = cant;
        }
    }
```

and the Adapter:

```
public class ProdfAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Prodf> {

        Context context;
        int layoutResourceId;   
        Prodf data[] = null;
        Context mContext;

        public ProdfAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Prodf[] data) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.mContext = context;
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            ProdfHolder holder = null;
            if(row == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
                holder = new ProdfHolder();
                holder.hldIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.fffIcon);
                holder.hldId = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.fID);
                holder.hldNume = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.fTitlu);
                holder.hldUm = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.fUM);
                holder.hldPu = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.fPU);
                holder.hldCant = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.fCant);
                row.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ProdfHolder)row.getTag();
            }
            Prodf produ = data[position];
            holder.hldId.setText(produ.id);
            holder.hldNume.setText(produ.nume);
            holder.hldUm.setText(produ.um);
            holder.hldPu.setText(produ.pu);
            holder.hldCant.setText(produ.cant);
            return row;
        }


        static class ProdfHolder
        {
            ImageView hldIcon;
            TextView hldId;
            TextView hldNume;
            TextView hldUm;
            TextView hldPu;
            TextView hldCant;
        }    
    }
```

- How do I use these, in a button click event, in order to add a full item to the custom layout listview?

Bellow id where I set the click button event and set the adapter for the listview. However I use different types in the adapter and in the add function... How do I fix them?

```
...
ArrayList<Prodf> produsele = new ArrayList<Prodf>();
....
Button badd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_addpro);
View.OnClickListener eventHandler2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
Prodf produsu = new Prodf(0, "id1", "numepro", "PCS", "3.20", "2");        
produsele.add(produsu);                
ProdfAdapter adapter = new ProdfAdapter(MyActivity.this,R.layout.prodf_item, produsele);
mylist.setAdapter(adapter);                             
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

As you will notice, my adapter extends ArrayAdapter and expects a Prodf[] , and when I populate the items I use an ArrayList . I think this is my problem, but I don't know how to make them get along... hence, I get compiler error:

**The constructor ProdfAdapter(MyActivity, int, ArrayList) is undefined**

I know why but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: you have to set this adapter to your listview

Comment: I do that, let me show it to you (I will edit the question to show it). I have a problem with populating the Arraylist and using the Adapter

Answer (score 0):

you have to:

- create an instance of the your adapter and [set it as the ListView adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29)
- bind an instance of an [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) to the button.
- in the [onClick(View v)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html#onClick%28android.view.View%29) method of the listener add the item to the adapter with one of the [add methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add%28T%29)

Comment: please check my edited question. I do all those things except adding item to the adapter correctly...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on my own. I had to change the Adapter to receive the same type of info I was adding in the click event. Now it works.